# Finding a de Bruijn sequence from a graph

Tags: graph-theory

[image: graph]

$DB_3$ is shown above. I used the Eulerian path: (000, 000, 001, 011, 111, 111, 110, 101, 011, 110, 100, 001, 010, 101, 010, 100, 000) and wrote down the labels of all the edges: 0111101100101000.

A de Bruijn sequence for $n=3$ should be of length $2^3=8$. How do I reduce the sequence above to 8 letters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The graph above is for the de Bruijn sequence $B(2,4)$: the nodes plus edges represent subsequences of length $3 + 1 =4.$ If you want $B(2,3)$ you should construct the de Bruijn graph on four vertices (00, 01, 10, 11) instead.

Comment: Thanks! That was very helpful.